# Define a custom exception in scriptA that can be caught by scriptB, which has imported scriptA

Tags: python, error-handling

If I want to define a custom exception in scriptA that can be caught by scriptB, which has imported scriptA, what would be the best practice?

Right now, I'm defining an exception in scriptA, then adding it to the `__builtins__` module:

```
# scriptA

class SomeError(Exception):
    pass

globals()['__builtins__'][SomeError.__name__] = SomeError

raise SomeError('Error from scriptA')
```

Then in scriptB, the error shows up:

```
# scriptB

import scriptA

scriptA.SomeError: Error from scriptA
```

Or I can handle the exception in scriptB:

```
# scriptB    

try:
    import scriptA
except SomeError, e:
    print e

Error from scriptA
```

I have been using a function to add the custom errors to the `__builtins__` module for multiple custom errors, but I imagine there is probably a better way of doing this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want scriptA to always raise an exception when being imported?  That seems like odd behavior.

Comment: That's just an example.. The point is to define a custom exception that can be handled in other scripts that have imported it.

Comment: But that's easy.  Just have B import sciptA and then do `except scriptA.SomeError`.  Or have B do `from scriptA import SomeError` and then do `except SomeError`.  You just can't have B catch an exception that scriptA raises during the import process.

Comment: Once again, that is just code that would work to demonstrate the concept, I'm not trying to raise an error like that lol.  I think I wasn't thinking about namespace when I was handling the error.  thanks.

Comment: And you really shouldn't be man-handling `globals()` like that in scriptA.